# Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity() returns always false on AJAX Call Cross Domain Origin

Tags: php, ajax, cordova, authentication, zend-framework

i'll have a problem connecting to an webservice, which returns JSON if called via url get parameters.
This call procedure is realised with AJAX, the problem in here is, that the "calling" Applikation as an webbased phonegap app, which is calling data via AJAX from Server.
To allow cross domain origin ajax calls, i already set headers for it in my php server side code:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
echo json_encode($array);
```

The problem about is that i try to auth before, auth works if i call the url directly in the browser, and all json calls are possible after...only if i use ajax the zend_auth identity get lost, it always returns that i'm not logged in.
Here's my AJAX JS code:

```
function loadTimeline()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            addItems(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://wishlistserver.localhost/timeline/get",true);

    xmlhttp.send();
}

function auth(username,password)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://wishlistserver.localhost/Login/login?username=" +     username     + "&password=" + password,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Here's the function which checks if i'm logged in:

```
if (!Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) {
            $errorInformation = array();
            $errorInformation["message"] = "No session";
            $errorInformation["code"] = "3";
            Application_Model_JsonajaxHandle::sendJSON($errorInformation);
            //end execution of controller actions
            exit;
        }
```

I'm looking forward for your help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could possibly be the explanation: The session ID (used by the server after you're logged in) is sent as a cookie, and since the request is cross-domain, it's considered a third party cookie by the browser. Several browsers will block third-party cookies, and the session is lost.

I struggeled with a similar issue, and ended up with this solution: Generate the session ID on the client (in the browser), use Javascript sessionStorage to store the session ID then send the session ID with each request to the server.

Since I didn't find many good answers around, I've written two articles detailing the solution:

[Javascript Cross-Domain Request With Session](https://404it.no/en/blog/javascript_cross-domain_request_with_session)

[CORS That Works In IE, Firefox, Chrome And Safari](https://404it.no/en/blog/cors_that_works_in_ie_firefox_chrome_and_safari)